# Django ListView paginate extra context

Tags: django, listview, pagination

I'm trying to pass different querysets to my template, for this i've overrided get_context_data like this:

```
class MainList(ListView):
    queryset = models.Tickets.objects.order_by('-pk')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'tickets_desc_pk'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tickets_inc_date'] = models.Tickets.objects.order_by('set_date')
        return context
```

Everything went ok, until i've decided to paginate my tables, paginate_by works only for main context(tickets_desc_pk).
Does anybody know, how to paginate another context? Or should i do this on client-side by JS/JQuery?

```
        <table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
    {% for ticket in tickets_inc_date %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ticket.pk }}</td>
            <td>{{ ticket.topic }}</td>
            <td>{{ ticket.set_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ ticket.priority }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
    {% for ticket in tickets_inc_date %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ticket.pk }}</td>
            <td>{{ ticket.topic }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, I would suggest using django-endless-pagination, it has worked well on all of my projects. You can read the documentation [here](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org).

Comment: thx a lot, it seems django cant handle my needs "from the box", or i'm too lazy to use generic views and write spagetti-code. I'll solve my question with ajax.